# Total stack sizes of threads in one process

Tags: linux, stack, pthreads

I use pthreads_attr_getthreadsizes() to get default stack size of one thread, 8MB on my machine.

But when I create 8 threads and allocate a very large stack size to them, say hundreds of MB, the program crash.

So, I guess, shall

```
("Number of threads" * "stack size per thread") < a constant value (e.g. virtual memory size)
```

?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by: `So, I guess, shall ("Number of threads" x "stack size of per thread") shall less than a value(virtual memory size)?`

Comment: Is dynamic allocation out of the question for you? Can you elaborate on why you need such a huge stack size? Usually, I end up shrinking mine down to 4mb .. sometimes less, for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".

The longer answer is that all of your threads share one virtual address space, and userspace-usable part of this space must be therefore be large enough to contain all thread stacks (as well as the code, static data, heap, libraries and any miscellaneous mappings).

Multi-hundred-megabyte stacks are a good indication that You're Doing It Wrong, as they say in the classics.

Comment: All I meant was that the runtime stack is not generally suitable for storing enormous data structures; you should be using heap allocation for such things.